# Unable to write using IIS FTP ... Keep getting Access is denied

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ftp, iis-7.5

I am having issues writing to my FTP site ... I am able to connect to the site using my FTP client. I have given the user account READ/WRITE authorizations inside of the IIS Web Site (which also handles FTP Publishing). I have also given the user account full control to the folder through the Security settings.

What am I missing? Because I can connect and browse the directories no problem ... I am leaning towards a permission issue.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the actual error message I receive using FileZilla:

```
Status: Starting upload of C:\Temp\Global.asax
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (64,34,179,104,207,165).
Command:    STOR Global.asax
Response:   550 Access is denied.
Error:  Critical file transfer error
```

This is a virtual server outside of our network ... hosted by another vendor. Internally we pass through a TMG server, and on the virtual server the Firewall is running ... I've tried turning it off ... but still have the same problem.

Comment: Is there an actual error message?

Comment: That might help! :) Just posted the error message.

Comment: Are you by any chance going trough an ISA Server?

Comment: What version of IIS & OS are you using anyway?

Comment: Internally TMG server ... site is hosted on an External web server with Windows Firewall running ... Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your TMG does not have the `Read-Only` flag set on outgoing FTP Connections:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/isablog/archive/2013/03/05/access-to-remote-ftp-server-through-tmg-2010-may-fail-with-error-550-access-denied.aspx

Comment: That did it! Thanks a ton! Didn't realize that out of the box TMG does not allow write/delete/upload access via FTP, we had to add the rule, then follow what that article said ... thanks again!

Comment: the link does not work / is password protected. Please provide a link that works.

Comment: You could just google for `TMG ftp read-only`, but aparently that's too much for sysadmins nowadays. I'll post another link.